# Pivot Table with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

```
select out.a,out.b from out
pivot (count([event]) for [date] in ([Mon],[Tues])) as event_count
group by out.a,out.b
```

while executing this query I am getting the following error:

> The multipart identifier out.a,out.b could not be bound

Answer (score 8):

Remove the `GROUP BY` clause, and the alias `out` of the columns `a` and `b` like so:

```
select a, b, [Mon], [Tues] 
from out
pivot 
(
  count([event]) 
  for [date] in ([Mon],[Tues])
) as event_count;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7f45/3)

**Note that:** When using the `PIVOT` table operator, you do not need to explicitly specify the grouping elements, in your case `a, b` or in the source table, you need to remove it from the the query and from the source table. The `PIVOT` operator will automatically figures out the columns you want to `GROUP BY`, and these columns are those that were not specified in either the `date` or the aggregation element the `event` in your case, the rest will be the grouped columns.

Thats why you have to list the columns' names explicitly instead of `FROM out`, incase the table `out` contains columns other than `a, b, date, event`. In this case, you have to do this:

```
select a, b, [Mon], [Tues] 
from
(
   SELECT a, b, "date", "event" 
   FROM out
) t
pivot 
(
  count([event]) 
  for [date] in ([Mon],[Tues])
) as event_count;
```

Answer (score 3):

sounds like you need replace out.a on [Mon] and out.b on [Tues]

```
SELECT [Mon], [Tues]
FROM out
PIVOT (
       COUNT([event]) FOR [date] in ([Mon],[Tues])
       ) AS event_count
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/943ea/2/0)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your query but may be this is what your looking for

```
Select a,b, [Mon],[Tues] from 
(
  Select a,b,date,event from out 
  group by a,b,date,event
)L
PIVOT
(
  count(event) for [date] in ([Mon],[Tues]) 
)  event_count
```