# How to do a PIVOT by day cycle in 31 days in month in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, pivot-table

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblProducts]
(
    [CATEGORY_ID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PRODUCT] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PRODUCTION_DATE] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I need to display total products of every day in month

Days should be pivoted

```
CATE   1 2 3 4 5 6 7.....30 (or 31)  -->days of month
CATE1  1 5                           --> count product by cate and day
CATE2  1 9
CATE3  5 10
```

Please note that PRODUCTION date is  from 6.00 am of the current date

to  5.59 a.m of the next date

That's my difficulty.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic pivot query:

```
Declare @month int = 1
; With data as (
    Select [CATEGORY_ID], [PRODUCT], [PRODUCTION_DATE] = DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(HOUR, -6, [PRODUCTION_DATE]))
    , [PRODUCT_YEAR] = DATEPART(YEAR, [PRODUCTION_DATE]), [PRODUCTION_MONTH] = DATEPART(MONTH, [PRODUCTION_DATE]) From [dbo].[tblProducts]
    --Where DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(HOUR, -6,[PRODUCTION_DATE])) = @month update if monthly/yearly query is needed
)
Select [CATEGORY_ID], [PRODUCTION_MONTH], [PRODUCTION_YEAR], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31]
From data
Pivot (
    Count([PRODUCT])
    For [PRODUCTION_DATE] In
    ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31])
    ) as piv
    Order By [CATEGORY_ID], [PRODUCTION_YEAR], [PRODUCTION_MONTH]
```

I basically offset everything by 6 hours (-6). 20150101 06:00 becomes midnight 20150101 00:00 and 5:59 become 23;59 on the previous day.

PIVOT: https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms177410%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx

Comment: Did you mean `DATEPART`, not `DATAPART`? Also instead of the [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) route, why not add PRODUCTION DATE's month in SELECT to Pivot out of all months in table, maybe even year, too.

Comment: Datepart was already fixed but thanks :) The CTE route is just a subquery. Don't see it as an evil CTE. Best pratice sugests to prepare the data with the 3 reauiered columns first in a subquery or CTE and then Pivot from it. The CTE is just easier to read and try on it's own. I am not sure I understand the last part of your comment.

Comment: Nothing against CTE. I am just suggesting you can run query without needing to pass a month parameter. Plus what if several years appear in table, you would be counting same month across all years. See my answer.

Comment: The question was about the offset of 6 hours. Not "write me my code" the way I wish it. I supposed the person asking would adapt it to its needs.

Comment: Indeed! Julien, I took your good code too literally, thinking ahead for the OP. Keep up with the MSSQL answers! See you around SO.

Comment: Thank you so much. I already copy and script running meet my needs.

Answer (score -1):

To add to @Julien's answer, you can [group with pivot by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853880/pivot-table-with-group-by) month and year of `PRODUCTION_DATE` without sending a parameter for each month using CTE.

```
SELECT 
    [CATEGORY_ID], [PRODUCTION_MONTH], [PRODUCTION_YEAR], 
    [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], 
    [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], 
    [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31]
FROM 
    (SELECT [CATEGORY_ID], [PRODUCT], 
            DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(HOUR, -6, [PRODUCTION_DATE])) AS [PRODUCTION_DAY]),   
            DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(HOUR, -6, [PRODUCTION_DATE])) AS [PRODUCTION_MONTH],
            DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(HOUR, -6, [PRODUCTION_DATE])) AS [PRODUCTION_YEAR] 
     FROM [dbo].[tblProducts]) As tmpProducts

PIVOT (
    Count([PRODUCT])
    FOR [PRODUCTION_DAY] In
       ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], 
        [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], 
        [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31])
    ) as piv
ORDER BY [CATEGORY_ID], [PRODUCTION_YEAR], [PRODUCTION_MONTH]
```

Example Output:

```
CATEGORY_ID PRODUCTION_MONTH    PRODUCTION_YEAR    1    2   3   4   5   6   7   8   ...
          1               1                2014   12    14  5   17  16  27  4   15
          1               2                2014   18    56  27  34  9   19  10  0
          1               1                2015   13    12  23  43  24  20  15  20
          1               2                2015   36    11  36  13  9   1   25  10
...
```

Comment: CTE or subquery are similar. I used a parameter because I thought he was only looking for a specific month.

Comment: Thank you so much. I already copy and script running meet my needs.